# Where to set working directory for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to open files using relative paths.
I'm using Visual Studio Code.

For some reason I have to specify the absolute path every time.
Is there a setting or configuration file in which I can set the working directory to the root directory of my project?

Comment: "I'm using Visual Studio on Mac coding in Golang". Are you sure you are not using Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I am using VS Code, sorry.
Do you know how to set it on VS Code?

Comment: Use https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues

Answer (score 0):

I had just resolve it some days before

add a configuration to launch.json

```
"cwd": "${fileDirname}"
```